# Limitations of process builder scheduled actions

Tags: process-builder, time-dependent-workflow

I'm trying to understand the limitations of process builder scheduled actions, I want to update more than 50000 records using time-based action. I tried time-based actions using workflow rule, but time-based workflow rule has following limitations (on an hourly basis) :

- Professional Edition: 250
- Enterprise Edition: 500
- Developer Edition: 50
- Unlimited and Professional Edition: 1,000

So I decided to use process builder scheduled actions, but I'm not sure how it will affect the huge amount of data. Is it possible with the only configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the process limit. You can refer it.

[image]

[Process Limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits.htm&type=5)

You will hit the limit but you can still use them. Once Salesforce reach the limit it carries forward them into next hours and Salesforce take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Across all versions, your org can have up to 20,000 process schedules based on a field and flow wait events based on relative time alarms.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled_limitations.htm&type=5

Only option is to go with batch apex :(